# How to access the Ansible getent module values & put into variable?

Tags: linux, unix, ansible, automation

I'm attempting to develop an Ansible playbook that uses the getent module to help manage various user accounts.  I would like to be able to access the various values like UID, GID, password, etc. (what I think is a Python dictionary -- but am not sure that is accurate).

How do I read/access if a password is lockecd (e.g. ! or !!)?
How do I read/access the UID or GID for say this account: 
    ntp:x:38:38::/etc/ntp:/sbin/nologin
into a variable to be used for the next task?

Here is current playbook task so far.  Can this be done if a playbook?

```
- name: "getent variables"
  getent:
    database: passwd
    key: ntp #root  #uid
    split: ':'
    #fail_key:
    # register: getent_passwd
- debug:
    var: getent_passwd
```

Answer (score 4):

Getent results will normally be added as facts to the hosts facts.

Keep in mind that the information about gid/uid/etc are in a separate database from information about passwords.

```
# ansible localhost -m getent -a 'database=passwd key=root'
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "getent_passwd": {
            "root": [
                "x", 
                "0", 
                "0", 
                "root", 
                "/root", 
                "/bin/bash"
            ]
        }
    }, 
    "changed": false
}

# ansible localhost -m getent -a 'database=shadow key=root' 
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "getent_shadow": {
            "root": [
                "*", 
                "17939", 
                "0", 
                "99999", 
                "7", 
                "", 
                "", 
                ""
            ]
        }
    }, 
    "changed": false
}
```

> How do I read/access the UID or GID for say this account: ntp:x:38:38::/etc/ntp:/sbin/nologin into a variable to be used for the next task?

It isn't that easy.

```
- name: "getent variables"
  getent:
    database: passwd
    key: ntp

- name: show the UID
  debug:
    var: getent_passwd['ntp'][1]

- name: show the GID
  debug:
    var: getent_passwd['ntp'][2]

- name: "getent variables"
  getent:
    database: passwd
    key: ntp

- name: show the password hash
  debug:
    var: getent_shadow['ntp'][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

*tl;dr - sample solutions to the problem with `getent` module (tricky) or `user` module (easier but more limited info)*

You can get the most info by using the `getent` module, but it's tricky to pick out the items you want (use `debug` to show you the whole structure so you can work out how to specify the fields that you want).

To fetch some common fields with `getent` for example,

```
 - ansible.builtin.set_fact:
     username: ntp
 - ansible.builtin.getent:
     database: passwd
     key: "{{ username }}"
 - ansible.builtin.set_fact:
     uid: "{{ getent_passwd[username][1] }}"
     gid: "{{ getent_passwd[username][2] }}"
     home: "{{ getent_passwd[username][4] }}"
     shell: "{{ getent_passwd[username][5] }}"
 - ansible.builtin.debug:
     msg: "UID: {{ uid }}, GID: {{ gid }}, home: {{ home }}, shell: {{ shell }}"
```

To reiterate Zoredache's comment, the `getent` module will create host facts of the form `getent_`*databasename* where *databasename* will correspond with the `database:` specified to `getent`, thus `getent_passwd` above.

If it's only those particular fields you want, you could instead use the easier to understand `user` module with `check_mode` (without `check_mode: true` the user concerned will be created or modified so take care!). The corresponding lines would be,

```
- ansible.builtin.user:
    name: ntp
  check_mode: true
  register: res 
- ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    uid: "{{ res.uid }}"
    gid: "{{ res.group }}"
    home: "{{ res.home }}"
    shell: "{{ res.shell }}"
- ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "UID: {{ uid }}, GID: {{ gid }}, home: {{ home }}, shell: {{ shell }}"
```